# jQuery Sortable sorting glitches

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a droppable and sortable in my project.

**My main problem is the following:**

1. Drag and Drop tiles in the tray
2. *Problem:* The sorting is buggy and it's difficult to place a tile where I want it to be.

It's weird, but I think if I start with an HTML code that already has tiles in the tray, this problem is not happening as much.

**Another thing I noticed:**

1. Grab a tile in the tray
2. Drag it outside the tray
3. Drag it back inside the tray at the very right part of the screen, where there is space
4. Drop the tile there
5. *Problem:* The tile will not sort to the right. However, It works fine when you don't drag the tile outside the tray while sorting.

Why are these happening?

```js
var gameContainer = $(".game");

var myTray = $(".tray").sortable({
  containment: gameContainer,
  helper: "clone",
  revert: 100,
  tolerance: "pointer",
  update: function(ev, ui) {
    ui.item.addClass("ontray").css({
      "left": "0px",
      "position": "static",
      "top": "0px"
    });
  }
}).disableSelection();

var setTileDraggable = function(tileSelector) {
  tileSelector.draggable({
    connectToSortable: myTray,
    containment: gameContainer,
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid"
  }).disableSelection();
};

var myBoard = $(".board").droppable({
  accept: ".tile",
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass("ontray")) {
      // tile (not red) coming from tray, place it into .tiles child div
      var cloneTile = ui.draggable.clone().removeClass("ontray").show();
      myBoard.children(".tiles").append(cloneTile);
      var dropx = ui.offset.left - myBoard.offset().left;
      var dropy = ui.offset.top - myBoard.offset().top;
      cloneTile.css({
        "left": dropx + "px",
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": dropy + "px"
      });
      setTileDraggable(cloneTile);
      ui.helper.remove();
      ui.draggable.remove();
    }
  }
}).disableSelection();

// set up draggables
setTileDraggable(myBoard.children(".tiles").find(".tile"));
```

```css
.game {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tile {
  background: #00e;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}

.board {
  bottom: 68px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tray {
  background: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.tray .tile {
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="game">
  <div class="board">
    <div class="tiles">
      <div class="tile">D</div>
      <div class="tile">B</div>
      <div class="tile">E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray">
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxDCt)